# How does maven know which life-cycle to run?

Tags: maven

a simple maven question here ?

Maven documentation said, there are three built-in life-cycles:

```
clean build(default) site
```

but how does maven know when to **enter** the `site` life-cycle?

Comment: It won't enter the `site` life-cycle until you tell it to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot run maven lifecycle by lifecycle name**. You have to invoke phases of lifecycles.

```
mvn <phase> //e.g., mvn compile
```

In the `site` lifecyle, Maven defined 4 phases, in this order:

```
<phases>
  <phase>pre-site</phase>
  <phase>site</phase>
  <phase>post-site</phase>
  <phase>site-deploy</phase>
</phases>
```

So, if you run `mvn site-deploy`, Maven knows you are in the `site` lifecyle. It will execute all the phases of the `site` lifecyle up to the `site-deploy` phase.

The order of execution will be: `pre-site > site > post-site >site-deploy`

Answer (score 0):

You must specify it on the mvn command line.

e.g. You can simply run

```
mvn site
```

Comment: that execute the `site` phase, not the life-cycle